# Why not unique_ptr made to accept only a temporary?

Tags: c++11, smart-pointers

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863603/how-to-make-template-rvalue-reference-parameter-only-bind-to-rvalue-reference) SO post seems to suggest that language indeed supports accepting temporaries only for arguments.

Why is then unique_ptr designed to accepted aliased pointers, like this:

```
auto ptr = new Widget{};
auto uptr = std::unique_ptr<Widget>(ptr);
```

Why not just restrict to:

```
auto uptr = std::unique_ptr<Widget>(new Widget{});
```

Comment: Why not restrict it to just `std::make_unique<Widget>()` instead?

Comment: The first scenario is actually pretty valid, though it could easily become exception-unsafe if more code is added between the two lines. The first pointer is said to be an observer pointer, while the `uptr` is called the "owning pointer". There's nothing wrong with having multiple observer pointers to the same resource. Also, `std::unique_ptr` should accept taking ownership from existing "raw owning pointers" so it can be used in existing codebases without breaking the existing APIs.

Comment: @KABoissonneault, in that case you could use `std::unique_ptr<Widget> up(std::move(ptr));` which flags that you are doing something potentially dangerous. See my answer.

Comment: @alfC It might just be me, but I don't think using rvalue references with fundamental types is ever the right solution to any problem.

Comment: @KABoissonneault, then the question is `unique_ptr` a fundamental type? It definitively is not like an `int` (pure value semantics). It is a matter of taste ultimately because it is a detail. But if we *all* (?) agree that "Not assigning an object(raw pointer) to a `unique/shared_ptr` as soon as it is created !" is a mistake then why not enforce it in the library, we now can enforce it and we also have a workaround if one wants to play dangerously. This is the typical thing that makes embarrassing to teach C++ to beginners.

Comment: @alfC: "*then the question is unique_ptr a fundamental type?*" He's talking about taking a `T*&&`. Pointers are fundamental types. As for the rest, we *don't* all agree. Or at least, not to the point where we should enforce it at the level of the library.

Comment: @NicolBolas, we in the technical evaluation of the problem. My problem is went we make smart-sounding "guideline" or call people ["dumb"](http://www.acodersjourney.com/2016/05/top-10-dumb-mistakes-avoid-c-11-smart-pointers/)  instead of recognizing that the library may have design oversights. We can at least say that the design has a strange case a recommend people to avoid something from that humble position. In this particular case a the alternative design has zero cost and we wouldn't need any extra guideline rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this doesn't help.

It's required that the pointer is created by a suitable allocation function for the given deleter, which is different to it being temporary.

You can't distinguish pointers created by a `new` expression, function call and by `&` operator by a value category - they are all rvalues.

Comment: "It's required that the pointer is created by using `new` expression" -- No, it's not. The default deleter requires this, but other deleters can and are used too.

Comment: Fair point. However, the `unique_ptr` constructor is not limited to the scenario mentioned by the OP, so any rationale that applies only to that scenario is somewhat flawed, in my opinion.

Comment: So, there is no way in C++ language to avoid this kind of aliased pointer?

Comment: @winterlight: No. You can always create a function that takes a pointer and returns an rvalue reference to that same pointer. Indeed, we have one; it's called `std::move`. You can always turn any non-rvalue expression into an rvalue expression.

Comment: @winterlight You can design your own `unique_ptr` class that can only be created with the `make_unique` factory function (tip: use private constructors and the `friend` keyword to achieve this).

Comment: @KABoissonneault, agreed.

Comment: @NicolBolas, "You can always turn any non-rvalue expression into an rvalue expression" - I see your point but somehow feel it is made too easy to pass an lvalue (`ptr`) to the unique_ptr constructor as in the question.

Comment: @winterlight: But passing an lvalue to the constructor is not an error.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good reason as far as I know, I think it this an underexploitation of the C++ language from the library.

I asked the same question [Why is raw pointer to shared_ptr construction allowed in all cases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37292414/why-is-raw-pointer-to-shared-ptr-construction-allowed-in-all-cases)

I still don't find a good reason for not making the constructor of `std::unique_ptr` accepting only r-value references, either from `new` or from a factory. Here I put it as answer and not as a comment to put it in at the same level of the other answer with which I don't agree.

If you really need to accept an existing pointer, you can always cast, that is use `std::move`. So it is not an excuse, because that is not the norm.